# perl cannot compile with error of lazy symbol binding not found for _mysql_init

Tags: mysql, perl

I'm running mac OS X Snow Leopard and I recognize that this is a common problem.

I have installed and reinstalled both the 32- and 64-bit binary installations of MySQL.

That didn't work, so I went ahead and (against my common sense) installed perl5 through macports to have an entirely different perl than the version that ships with Snow Leopard.

I re-installed `DBI` and `DBD::mysql` modules into the new perl, both with success.

And yet still:

```
me$ perl5 processmail
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/darwin-      2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
  Expected in: dynamic lookup

dyld: Symbol not found: _mysql_init
  Referenced from: /opt/local/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.9/darwin-2level/auto/DBD/mysql/mysql.bundle
  Expected in: dynamic lookup
```

I have also tried `perl5 processmail --mysql_config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`.

Thanks in advance

Comment: There's nothing wrong with installing a macports perl -- it's generally preferred to install your own perl and leave the system one alone (especially on OSX, which still uses 5.10.0).

Comment: it's not the idea i don't trust. it's macports itself. but the question remains.

Comment: with `sudo port install perl5.12` you get the latest stable perl version. And i tend to recommend local::lib to mess around at $HOME. but i guess still the question remains..

Comment: I hate to 'bump' but I really need to figure this one out.

Comment: you can [add a bounty to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty) in order to seek more answers.  The system will chip in 50 rep points to help you out.  Please don't ask this again or try to bump it some other way.  Asking the same question again is considered abuse of the system, and editing to bump your question will (eventually) result in your losing control of it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you get the same error running your perl script as root?

Does your shell environment possibly have VERSIONER_PERL_PREFER_32_BIT=no set?

there's more info about both of these at http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=793727

Answer (score 0):

I just finally solved this on our box by getting rid of the default setting

defaults delete com.apple.versioner.perl

Suddenly it just works!  Whatever